# REdhat Bond traffic to single port; iptables or routing?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I've been struggling to find an answer to this, we are running a server that has a "management interface" eth0, and an "application interface" eth1. Both operate on port 80, we want to be able to say any traffic that originates from eth0, goes out eth0, and traffic from eth1 goes out eth1. We don't want the default route to overrule the output of the traffic.

I've been searching through iptable documents, and seeing if there were any route rules that could be used, but can't seem to find anything to be an adequate solution.

Comment: Traffic usually doesn't "originate from an interface". Do you want to different applications to claim eth0 and eth1 on port 80? Do you have different address on eth0 and eth1 (`ip addr`)? Can your applications bind to interfaces? If not, have you considered putting them into a network namespace, and moving one eth into that namespace?

Comment: Yes each port has their own IP address. The management and application both are websites, and tied to port 80.

Comment: So you have (at least) two programs, one for management, and one for application. What programs are these exactly? Web servers? Apache? Something else? Are they able to bind on a specific interface, via configuration or commandline options?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found the answer after a lot of digging, the answer was Policy Routing:
http://commandline.ninja/2013/01/14/centos-policy-routing-why-yes-it-can-be-done/

Comment: We're glad you found a solution and came back here to report it. However, this answer is link-only, and not particularly helpful if the link expires or changes. It is better to copy the relevant parts of the answer into the answer post itself, and leave the link for attribution and additional information. That way, if the link goes bad, your answer is still good.